# Redirect unauthorized requests to Azure AD for login

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory

I've got a WebAPI instance running in Azure that is secured with Azure AD. A mobile app connects to this API using bearer tokens, works great. When I try calling the API from the browser, though, it returns a 401 because I'm not logged in. That's true because I'm not presented with a login screen.

My API doesn't have any UI so what I'd want it to do is to forward the user to Azure AD login and return to the API endpoint they were calling after authentication.

If I go to the Azure portal, there's a setting that says "Action to take when the request is not authorized". If I set that one to "Log in with Azure Active Directory", it behaves the way I want it to. But... I have some endpoints which need to be accessed anonymously, and this setting catches **all** requests, not caring about any [AllowAnonymous] attributes.

So any request to an endpoint labeled Authorize that is not authorized yet should be forwarded to Azure AD login, all others should be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `DelegatingHandler` to your web api project and register it in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new UnAuthorizedDelegatehandler());

public class UnAuthorizedDelegatehandler: DelegatingHandler
```

There you can check for 401 status codes and do the redirect to whatever and also apply a redirect url as querystring parameter.

```
HttpResponseMessage rm = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
if (rm.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
{
    // configure the redirect here
    return rm;                        
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a valid solution. I'm going to leave it open for a while though cause I kinda expect there might be an even easier way to do the same.