# authenticate front end with web apis

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a .net core application that I'm trying to authenticate with azure ad. 
I'm using C# web apis for for all backend.
The place where I'm getting stuck is how to force my user to login when coming to my app. 
If I add `Authorize` to my api calls with  they just fail and the page loads without getting the information from the api calls. 
How do I tell my react app to go to the microsoft login page if they're not logged in? I'm thinking that I don't need tokens because I can just get the ms login link from my api call and login? 
Is this something I can set in the startup page?

Comment: On your UI, do a generic error handling on your API call and if you are getting 401, handle it and redirect it to login page.

Comment: thank you, my issue is what is the login page while authenticating with azure ad?

Comment: there's this long url https://login.microsoftonline.com with a bunch of parameters that gets set automatically if I'm not authorized. So you you say I should check if it's a 401 and if it is call another api that gives me back the url with the client id etc etc and redirect there?

Comment: see this approach, this can also be used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774500/redirect-unauthorized-requests-to-azure-ad-for-login

Comment: thank you, I'm going to try to implement that approach and see where it takes me.

Comment: where would I get the url to redirect the user to? generate it manually?

Comment: Check it in the Azure configuration. IT should be there or, just put it as hard-coded string with the returnUrl which you were actually targeting to access before authentication.

Comment: I can hardcode it - I'm just thinking am I going about this the wrong way? would it correct to use tokens? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493931/azure-ad-auth-with-angular-and-netcore2-webapi

Comment: So, once your app is authorized and token is generated it will not do it again and again.This will be implicit once you configure your web APIs with AD in your startup file

Comment: got it. thank you. I ended up using this comment that you wrote above.   - On your UI, do a generic error handling on your API call and if you are getting 401, handle it and redirect it to login page. Would you say to put it in an answer?

Comment: Yes. If that helped you that's the answer

Comment: Hey, would you like to mark an answer. It will help.

Comment: Do you want to mark it so I can give you credit? I think I might be going about this the wrong way though - I think I'm supposed to be authenticating client side first and then passing with tokens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378607/cors-error-when-adding-azure-ad-authentication